# How to create "where int in [1,2,3]" query in dotnet ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a function that takes a parameter of string[].
StoreHierarchy has a property named AreaNbr, which is a int.

```
public Task<IEnumerable<StoreHierarchy>> GetStoreHierarchyByAreas(string[] areas)
{
}
```

I would like to create the following equivalent query in dotnet core

```
select * from StoreHierarchy
where AreaNbr in areas // (['13','12'....])
```

Since the parameter is string[] I would need to convert to an int[]. Is this query possible in either query or method synatx? If possible please provide both so I can compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious:

```cs
public Task<IEnumerable<StoreHierarchy>> GetStoreHierarchyByAreas(string[] areas)
{
    var areasInt = areas.Select(a => int.Parse(a));
    return ctx.StoreHierarchy.Where(h => areasInt.Contains(h.AreaNbr));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much 
I was trying to do it this way:
return ctx.StoreHierarchy.Where(h => h.AreaNbr.Contains(areaInt));

Now I realize the error in my ways .